# Oracle NLS function/settings file location

Tags: oracle, translation, jdeveloper, nls, oracle12c

I am working on a Oracle Jdeveloper project that was made by another person which I can no longer contact. On the code he uses this: nls['NO_ROWS_FOUND'].

I have made some searches and I found that this goes to file that stores oracle environment variables for language translations and loads the corresponding value for that key variable. (Not sure if this is true).

What I would like to know is how can I find this file, or where are these values stored? Can I had diferent translations?

He is using this to enter text on a Label.

Thanks
Best Regards

Comment: How is "nls" declared?

Comment: How can I see that? How is it declared, so I can make a search on that? Is this stored on DB? I am really new to ADF and I am starting to understand this. Sorry for providing fewer information.

Comment: Tray this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/68943654/13583945 maybe works for you