# ORACLE NLS_LANG

Tags: sql, oracle

How set and check NLS_LANG settings? I did

```
set NLS_LANG = DANISH_DENMARK.WE8ISO8859P2
```

in command prompt but I don't know if it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the OS  and on the command interpreter:

Linux/bash:

```
echo $NLS_LANG
export NLS_LANG=...
```

Windows/cmd.exe:

```
echo %NLS_LANG%
set NLS_LANG=...
```

Make sure to have **no space** before and after `=`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the SO is Windows, Just I find the register for 'NLS_LANG' in the regedit, and i put the value that i need (Spanish = ESA), then i put 'LATIN AMERICAN SPANISH_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1'.

[WIndows reg edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DssNZ.jpg)

Then i verify the change on TOAD.

[TOAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk56J.jpg)

This fix  the issue that some views that have an condition like this 'AND BDT.LANGUAGE = USERENV ('lang');', do not return any row.

In my case i neded 'ESA'.

You can run this to see what do you have seated.

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'lang') FROM dual;
SELECT USERENV('LANGUAGE') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/nt.816/a73010/appc.htm):

> The NLS_LANG parameter uses the following format:
>
> NLS_LANG = LANGUAGE_TERRITORY.CHARACTER_SET
>
> where:
>
> - LANGUAGE - Specifies the language and conventions for displaying messages, day name, and month name.
> - TERRITORY - Specifies the territory and conventions for calculating week and day numbers.
> - CHARACTER_SET - Controls the character set used for displaying messages.

You will be able to find the commonly used NLS_LANG configurations in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/nt.816/a73010/appc.htm#1020334).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows type `set` at the command line and it will dump out all the environment variables which have been set up.

Note that under Windows, environment variables which are set at the command line in a command line process are **not seen** by anything *except* that command line process. If you want to create a permanent environment variable - one which is remembered and used by all other processes - you'll need to go to Control Panel - System - Advanced System Settings - click on the "Environment Variables" button towards the bottom of the dialog - create the variable and value you want in the "System Variables" pane (the lower one on the dialog), and click "OK" to save your changes. To check, open a *new* Command Line window, type "set" at the command prompt, and verify that the variable you just set is shown in the list with the correct value.

Comment: or  use `setx NLS_LANG nls_lang_value` in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Hey! I learned something new today! OK - back to sleep... :-)